# How do I play music on loop in batch?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I've gotten some code that makes `wmplayer` play in the background, but I can't get it to loop itself after it's done. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
@echo off
set "file=GameMusic.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
exit /b
```

Comment: Did you mean play the music in infinite loop or you can fix the number of loop to play ?

Comment: Play the music in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try for this modified code and give me your feedback :

```
@echo off
set "file=GameMusic.mp3"
( 
  echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.settings.volume = 100
  echo Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
)>sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
exit /b
```

***EDIT :***
The second script should works give it a try ;)

```
@echo off
set "file=GameMusic.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.settings.volume = 100
  echo Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
  echo      WScript.Sleep 100
  echo Wend
)>sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
exit /b
```

Comment: I tried this out. It loops, but only once, then suddenly cuts off one the second loop.

Comment: The `Sound.settings.volume` also helped alot.

Comment: @FudgeMuffins Just i wonder what's the duration time of your mp3 file `GameMusic.mp3` ? and if you can of course share with us your game project, because i'm interesting to take a look for the whole code. You can post it if you like on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Its around 2 minutes. The program is in progress right now, but here is the link:

Comment: @FudgeMuffins Edit your comment and re-post the link please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108866/discussion-between-hackoo-and-fudgemuffins).

Comment: Sleep 100 is 100 seconds? Also will this code play .wav files instead pf mp3?

Answer (score 2):

In vbscript you can do something like that with a fixed loop number.

You can get rid of `wscript.echo` after testing it !

```
Option Explicit
Dim SoundFile,i,MaxLoop
MaxLoop = 3
SoundFile = "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3"
For i = 1 to MaxLoop
    wscript.echo "This the "& i & " loop"
    Call Play(SoundFile)
Next    
'*******************************************
Sub Play(SoundFile)
    Dim oPlayer
    Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
' Play audio
    oPlayer.URL = SoundFile
    oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
    oPlayer.controls.play 
    While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend
' Release the audio file
    oPlayer.close
End Sub
'*******************************************
```

Or something like that with infnite loop when we add this line :

> oPlayer.settings.setMode "loop", True

```
Option Explicit
Dim SoundFile
SoundFile = "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3"
Call Play(SoundFile)
'*******************************************
Sub Play(SoundFile)
    Dim oPlayer
    Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
' Play audio
    oPlayer.URL = SoundFile
    oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
    oPlayer.settings.setMode "loop", True
    'MsgBox oPlayer.settings.getMode("loop")        
    oPlayer.controls.play 
    While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend
' Release the audio file
    oPlayer.close
End Sub
'*******************************************
```

So, you can generate a vbscript file and call it from a batch file like this :

```
@echo off
Call :Play "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Intro_DJ.mp3"
::***************************************************
:Play <SoundFile>
(
    echo Option Explicit
    echo Dim SoundFile
    echo SoundFile = Wscript.arguments(0^)
    echo Call Play(SoundFile^)
    echo '*******************************************
    echo Sub Play(SoundFile^)
    echo    Dim oPlayer
    echo    Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
    echo    oPlayer.URL = SoundFile
    echo    oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
    echo    oPlayer.settings.setMode "loop", True       
    echo    oPlayer.controls.play 
    echo    While oPlayer.playState ^<^> 1
    echo        WScript.Sleep 100
    echo    Wend
    echo    oPlayer.close
    echo End Sub
    echo '*******************************************
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Start "" "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
Exit /b
::***************************************************
```

And for more ***fun***, i added a typewriter with speaking voice and a ShowBalloonTip function here :

```
@echo off
Title Playing music in loop with a typewriter, speaking voice and ShowBalloonTip by Hackoo 2016
Color 0A & Mode con cols=85 lines=3
Set "Msg=  We are playing music in loop. And to stop it, just kill the wscript.exe process."
Call :TypeWriter "%Msg%"
Call :PS_Sub 'Warning' 100 "'Playing Music in loop'" "'%Msg%'" 'Warning'
Call :Play "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Intro_DJ.mp3"
pause>nul
::***************************************************
:Play <SoundFile>
(
    echo Option Explicit
    echo Dim SoundFile
    echo SoundFile = Wscript.arguments(0^)
    echo Call Play(SoundFile^)
    echo '*******************************************
    echo Sub Play(SoundFile^)
    echo    Dim oPlayer
    echo    Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
    echo    oPlayer.URL = SoundFile
    echo    oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
    echo    oPlayer.settings.setMode "loop", True       
    echo    oPlayer.controls.play 
    echo    While oPlayer.playState ^<^> 1
    echo        WScript.Sleep 100
    echo    Wend
    echo    oPlayer.close
    echo End Sub
    echo '*******************************************
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Start "" "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
Exit /b
::***************************************************
:TypeWriter
Cls
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 150
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
echo Set Voice=CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice"^)
echo voice.speak strText
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cScript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
exit /b
::***************************************************
:PS_Sub $notifyicon $time $title $text $icon
Rem Thanks to Aacini Tip here http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=8987#p8987
PowerShell  ^
  [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms') ^| Out-Null; ^
  [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing') ^| Out-Null; ^
   $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon; ^
   $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::%1; ^
   $notify.visible = $true; ^
   $notify.showballoontip(%2,%3,%4,%5)
%End PowerShell%
exit /B
::***************************************************
```

Comment: That's pretty cool! I still want to use the current VBS script though. Is that possible?

Comment: @FudgeMuffins What did you mean about the current script ? explain more !

Comment: The one im using right now, the one I posted in my question.

Answer (score 1):

From using Object Browser in Office (Alt + F11, F2, Alt + T, R, add Windows Media Player (using wmp.dll).

```
Sub setMode(bstrMode As String, varfMode As Boolean)
    Member of WMPLib.IWMPSettings
    Sets the mode of the playlist
```

From Help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564867(v=vs.85).aspx

`autoRewind` Tracks are restarted from the beginning after playing to the end.

`loop` The sequence of tracks repeats itself.

`showFrame` The nearest key frame is displayed when not playing. This mode is not relevant for audio tracks.

`shuffle` Tracks are played in random order.

`varfMode` [in]
A System.Boolean value specifying whether the new specified mode is active.

So `Sound.SetMode "Loop", True`

```
Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
oPlayer.URL = "C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav"
oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
oPlayer.settings.setMode "loop", True       
oPlayer.controls.play 
wscript.sleep 10000
```

Comment: Where would I put that in my script? Sorry, but I'm a little new to VBS and batch.

Comment: after `echo Sound.URL = "%file%"`

Comment: I get an error. It says the `Object does not support this property or method: 'Sound.SetMode'.`

Comment: `oPlayer.setmode` etc. I did link to help. Here's the vbs help https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

Comment: Figured it out, I have to do `Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are supposed to be a vbscript programmer. I've shown you how to look up methods and properties. Where the help is. Try reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code by writing the code that i posted to you into function and you call it what you want !
This an example :

```
@echo off
echo We play "Intro_DJ.mp3" with a volume of 20
Call:PlayMusic http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Intro_DJ.mp3 20
echo(
echo Hit any key to stop the music and play another file
pause>nul
Call:StopMusic
Call:PlayMusic http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3 100
echo(
echo We play "Matrix.mp3" with a volume of 100
echo(
echo Hit any key to stop the music in loop
pause>nul
Call:StopMusic
Exit /b
::************************************************************
:PlayMusic <Media_URL> <Volume>
( 
    echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
    echo Sound.URL = "%1"
    echo Sound.settings.volume = %2
    echo Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True
    echo Sound.Controls.play
    echo While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
    echo      WScript.Sleep 100
    echo Wend
)>%~n0.vbs
start "" "%~n0.vbs" %1 %2
Exit /b
::************************************************************
:StopMusic
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F>nul 2>&1
Exit /b
::************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my collection of console players that rely only on windows build-in objects.

1) [MediaRunner.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/mediarunner.bat)  - it uses windows media player object.To finish it checks its state - when player state is `1` the playing is finished.Usage:

```
 MediaRunner.bat someSound.wav
```

2) [SpPlayer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/spplayer.bat) it uses sp.voice objects .Though it's pretty lightweight it can play only `.wav` files.Usage is the same..

3) [SoundPlayer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/soundPlayer.bat)  - it uses the internetexplorer.application object and its `bgsound` tag (and does not require installed media player).It calculates in advance the length of the file to decide when to exit.Also accept as optional argument music volume:

```
 SoundPlayer.bat someFile.mp3 500
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my scipt, followed Mr. Hackoo (how do I tag the person?) answer but getting error, need help team.

```
@echo off
set "file=notify.wav"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
 echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
echo Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True
echo Sound.Controls.play
echo While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
echo      WScript.Sleep 100
echo Wend
)>sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
exit /b
```

and the error I'm getting after I double click this file is

[image]