# Stop background audio when exit in Batch and how to delimit loop

Tags: batch-file, audio

Well, I'm starting with Batch, and I would like to know how to stop the background audio I executed when I exit of the .bat file without using the task manager. I'm using this to execute audio and looping it:

```
set "file=music1.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.settings.volume = 100
  echo Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
  echo WScript.Sleep 100
  echo Wend
 )>sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
```

The other question would be how to delimit loop, because I don't know how to stop it at a certain amount of loops. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to loop? Is there code in the batch file, or is it in the VBScript? Be more specific and show a better example.

Comment: yes, there is code, it's a batch videogame. I put that code at the begining so the music start when I open the .bat so there is no problem with that. The problem comes when I shut the window and the music doesn't stop, so I have to terminate the process with the task manager. What I want is to stop the process when I exit the videogame. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have a batch file that can do something before it closes if the user presses the X button.

Comment: I think you're right... well, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This code is inspired from this :  [How do I play music on loop in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524002/how-do-i-play-music-on-loop-in-batch)

```bat
@echo off
Title Play Music in loop and stop it
Call:StopMusic
echo We play "EuroDance 90 Radio" with a volume of 20
Call:PlayMusic https://stream.initialradio.fr:8443/djbuzz-192k.mp3 20
echo(
echo Hit any key to stop the music and play volume 100
pause>nul
Call:StopMusic
cls
Call:PlayMusic https://stream.initialradio.fr:8443/djbuzz-192k.mp3 100
echo(
echo We play "DJ Buzz Radio" with a volume of 100
echo(
echo Hit any key to stop the music in loop
pause>nul
Call:StopMusic
Exit /b
::************************************************************
:PlayMusic <Media_URL> <Volume>
( 
    echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
    echo Sound.URL = "%1"
    echo Sound.settings.volume = %2
    echo Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True
    echo Sound.Controls.play
    echo While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
    echo      WScript.Sleep 100
    echo Wend
)>%~n0.vbs
start "" "%~n0.vbs" %1 %2
Exit /b
::************************************************************
:StopMusic
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F>nul 2>&1
Exit /b
::************************************************************
```

Comment: Yes, I was reading your answers but I couldn´t achieve what I wanted. I'm making a game in batch, and I want the music to stop just when I shut the batch window. Do you know how to do it? Thanks again.

Comment: @D.Patch Can you share your the source code of your videogame batch ?